# Typescript Type Union are not working properly

Tags: typescript, prisma

I'm using Prisma in one of my projects and I have two delegates that have almost the exact type (SaleOffer, RentOffer), so I have a function that returns either delegate depending on the arguments so the function type is

```js
prisma_delegate:(offerType)=> PrismaClient['SaleOffer'] | PrismaClient['RentOffer']
```

and it's throwing errors all over the place.
when I cast it into one of the types it works, so

```js
// The Following two work properly without any warnings
(prisma_delegate(offerType) as PrismaClient['RentOffer']).findUnique(...);
(prisma_delegate(offerType) as PrismaClient['SaleOffer']).findUnique(...);

//But this one even though the code works properly it gives a warning
(prisma_delegate(offerType) as PrismaClient['RentOffer'] | PrismaClient['SaleOffer']).findUnique(...);
```

The TS error is "Find Zero or One SaleOffer that matches the filter. Find Zero or One RentOffer that matches the filter"

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you're trying to define the return type of the function, correct?

Could you try something like this

```
import { PrismaClient, RentOffer, SaleOffer } from '@prisma/client'

function foo(args : any) : Promise<RentOffer | null | SaleOffer> {
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: it won't work.
I'm accessing a specific delegate from the PrismaClient itself and calling functions from it.
to describe the issue in a simpler manner imagine i have a variable 
```js
var x: boolean|number = ...
x.toString() // should work with no errors because they both have the function.
```
in may case PrismaClient['SaleOffer'] and PrismaClient['RentOffer'] both have findUnique that accepts the same arguments but it throws an error

Comment: Could you create a small reproduction of the problem? It's a bit difficult to provide a solution without the exact types available :/